# text message notifications on my lock screen of my galaxy s 3

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

I have just gotten a galaxy s 3 and am trying to get the notifications of a new message to show up at a push notification on my lock screen. I have looked for setting to change to do so but can't find anything other than the message showing up in my lock screen. Can someone help me? ?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts Melanie. Please clarify your question: you say that messages are showing on your lock screen but then you say push notifications aren't? Please describe exactly what you are seeking to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no setting for this unfortunately.

Samsung will occasionally update the S3 with OS updates such as recently to 4.3 which changed the way text messages are displayed on the lock screen.  So it not only depends on which version of Android you are running but which Samsung update you have got.

Perhaps you can try download a lock screen replacement app from the Play Store?

Comment: Please rephrase your answer listing what versions do not have this. Perhaps a snipped from a Samsung blog for the changes? Is the latest version 4.4, which had this feature/bug?

Comment: my point was that you can't control how the built in lock screen functions and there are no settings provided, and further, its features may change every update they do. Its not a feature I keep track of specifically, but noticed that it happened in general with samsung

Answer (score 0):

That's weird.  I have an S2 and when I get a message I can swipe the message notifications action and it gets me right to the message.  If you didn't find anything  maybe you can add messaging as an unlock shortcut to get you right to your messages.